# obtain data from mysql comma separated

Tags: mysql

I have a column in my table 'refer'(column) 'chart1'(table) with values 49,47,50 so on for each person
Now I have to take these numbers and get details of users with 49,47,50 in other table 'users'

users(table)

```
Name  id  address
xxx   49   bnm
yyy   47   kjh
zzz   50   jhg
```

chart1(table)

```
Name  refer     accounts
aaa   49,50      12547
bbb   47,49,50   32546
```

Now I need to get the details of 'xxx' 'yyy' 'zzz' accordingly by the refer column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you can, change your database schema. :)

If not, you will have to split the column "refer", see [MySQL Split String Function](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/).